# Why are almost all inborn errors of metabolism autosomal recessive?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, health

Technically, the only inborn error of metabolism I know that is autosomal dominant is acute intermittent porphyria. Also, the only inborn of metabolism I know that is X-linked recessive is Lesch-Nyhan syndrome.

Comment: Have you considered what the effect would be if the error of metabolism was autosomal dominant?  How likely would it be that the affected individual would live long enough to reproduce and pass it on (etc., etc.)

Comment: i would suggest doing more research into mechanisms of the various inborn errors and seeing what you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most deleterious mutations are partial or complete loss-of-function (LOF) mutations; most of those can be functionally compensated for by the presence of a wild-type (normal) copy on the other chromosome and so are recessive. Genes on the non-pseudoautosomal parts of X or Y are effectively hemizygous in males and thus LOF mutations there will likely be dominant.  Such LOF mutations in females may also be dominant, depending on whether mosaic expression (due to X-inactivation) results in the phenotype.

Comment: From [How do I write a good answer?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the [help], *`Answer well-asked questions. Not all questions can or should be answered here.`*